# Is it possible to select the properties of a node a XPATH?

Tags: xpath

I have an XML of the form:

```
<articleslist>
    <articles>
        <originalId>507948</originalId>
        <title>Hogan Lovells Training Contract</title>
        <slug>hogan-lovells-training-contract</slug>
        <metaTitle>Hogan Lovells Training Contract</metaTitle>
        <metaDescription>Find out about the Hogan Lovells Training Contract and Application Process</metaDescription>
        <language>en</language>
        <disableAds>false</disableAds>
        <shortUrl>false</shortUrl>
        <category_slug>law</category_slug>
        <subcategory_slug>industry</subcategory_slug>
        <updatedAt>2021-03-15T18:38:51.058+00:00</updatedAt>
        <createdAt>2018-11-29T06:42:51.665+00:00</createdAt>
    </articles>
</articlelist>
```

I'm able to select the row values with the XPATH `//articles`.

How can I select the child properties of articles (i.e. the column headings), so I get back a list of the form:

```
originalId
title
slug
etc...
```

Comment: look at string-join to create a delimited list, or use xquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your XPath version.

In XPath 2.0 it's simply `//articles/*/name()`

In 1.0 it's not possible because there's no such data type as a "sequence of strings". You would have to return the set of elements as `//articles/*`, and then extract their names in the calling program.